# Python how do I get the length of a class byte list

Tags: python, class, byte

I am using email IMAP4, and I get the number of emails with a given subject like below list, I also get it's type. My goal is to get the size or length of it:

```
  emailsUIDs = [b'80 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 93 126 136 137 138 139 140']
  print(type(emailsUIDs ))  # Prints --> type of Object =  <class 'list'>

  myLen = len((str(emailsUIDs ).replace("b'", "").replace("'", "")).split())
```

I tried len(emailsUIDs ) but I only get 1, is there a better way to get the length of emailsUIDs  and not have to do string manipulation as I am doing

Comment: The length of your list *is 1*, so what do you actually mean? Note, `.replace("b'", "")` does *nothing* and is pointless. And no, there is no built-in function that understands "the length that user3556956 is thinking about when it asks for the length of this list with a single string element and that length is dependent on some tokanization of said string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list with one element (a bytes object). You need to do this to extract the list of ids:

```
emailsUIDs = [b'80 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 93 126 136 137 138 139 140']
ids_bytes = emailsUIDs[0]
ids_bytes_list = ids_bytes.split()
ids_list = map(int, ids_bytes_list)
```

then you can use the id's in numerical form from that list, or if you just needed the count you could have simply done `len(ids_bytes_list)` straight.

Comment: They don't want to use string manipulation... elso, the encoding isn't really necessary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's not encoding, it's decoding. He has a bytes object there which needs to be converted to string. How else are you going to count the number of id's in that bytes sequence? You can't do any sort of split on that, unless you actually convert it to string.

Comment: Thank you "andreihondrari" Thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @andreihondrari yes, sorry, I meant decode, but you can split bytes objects just fine, and you can pass bytes objects to `int` just fine as well. Try `list(map(int, emailsUIDs[0].split()))`

Comment: Yeah, I mean, note, `bytes` objects are simply just Python 2 `str` objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga updated my answer with your better version.